# Enabling dBase on PHP installed on Centos

Tags: php, centos, yum, php5

I have php 5.3.6 installed on Centos 5.5 (from iucommunity repository). Now when I want to enable dBase by yum install php-dbase, I get this error:

```
Package php-dbase is obsoleted by php-common, trying to install php-common-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.i386 instead
Package matching php-common-5.1.6.27.el5_5.3.i386 already installed. Checking for update.
Nothing to do
```

Probably, because I have installed php with yum install php53. How can I enable dBase on my current server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it said, `php-dbase` is obsoleted and you should install `php53-common` instead:

```
# yum --enablerepo=iuscommunity install php53-common
```

Comment: but php53-common has already been installed

Comment: What do you want to do with `php-dbase`?

Comment: Although it is an old system with no interesting feature; but I believe it is quite fast for simple storage on flatfile (e.g. one column data in the form of key/value where key is ID which is identical to line number).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the function calls are actually not there?  Try calling them - it sounds like they are already part of common now.

Comment: Yes, the library of dbase does not exist in php extensions. When running a dbase command, I get error of "Fatal error: Call to undefined function dbase_create()"